# No audio - audio card not detected

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio

I have brand new installation of KUbuntu 20.10 dualboot with Windows 10 on Asus Zenbook 14 um425ia and my speakers are not working. I see only Dummy Output.

I can fix this with reinstalling pulseaudio `sudo apt reinstall pulseaudio` but after reboot the issue is back. Speakers don't work but headphones do.

I also found when I boot to KUbuntu with headphones already plugged in and then I unplug them, speakers start to work. What should I do with it?

I found this in syslog:

```
Nov 21 13:07:53 ZenBook pulseaudio[861]: Failed to find a working profile.
Nov 21 13:07:53 ZenBook pulseaudio[861]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="2" name="pci-0000_04_00.6" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_04_00.6" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
```

output of `sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*`:

```
/dev/snd/controlC0:  matej       933 F.... pulseaudio
                     matej       938 F.... pipewire-media-
/dev/snd/controlC1:  matej       938 F.... pipewire-media-
/dev/snd/controlC2:  matej       933 F.... pulseaudio
                     matej       938 F.... pipewire-media-
/dev/snd/seq:        matej       932 F.... pipewire
```

output of `inxi -SMA`:

```
System:    Host: ZenBook Kernel: 5.8.0-29-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.19.5 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: ZenBook UX425IA_UM425IA v: 1.0 serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: UX425IA v: 1.0 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: UX425IA.307 
           date: 09/16/2020 
Audio:     Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor driver: snd_rn_pci_acp3x 
           Device-3: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 17h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-29-generic
```

output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. Device 500c (rev 01)
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev c2)
04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1637
04:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
04:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
04:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
04:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
04:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
05:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
05:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
```

**EDIT:
It was a bug in pulseaudio and it got patched.**

Comment: Install `pavucontrol` you can change sound output there manually.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz There is only dummy output there.